# Paint Applet graphics onto a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet

I have been trying to paint the graphics of an Applet when Applet.setVisible(false); and painting it onto my JPanel when JPanel.visible(true);

I tried to use Image i = Applet.createImage(width,height); and then paint the image to my JPanel with g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);

All I am left with is a blank JPanel when JPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g)... is invoked.

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: If the applet is painted with a BufferedImage, why not just pass that to the JPanel? What is the overall effect you're trying to achieve? Please tell us more of the important details of your problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the `Applet` won't draw when it's visibility is set to `false`, which explains why your `JPanel` is coming up blank.  Is it necessary for you to hide the `Applet`?  A typical solution would be to add the `Applet` directly to the `JPanel` by calling:

```
myJPanel.add(myApplet);
```

Of course, this mixes Swing and AWT components, which some people will object to, but it still works.  Note however that a single instance of an `Applet` cannot be drawn to two places at once, so you cannot add your `Applet` to the `JPanel` and another place at the same time.

Comment: The point is to almost mimic the effect of a "glass pane" so that I can view the applet, but not send/receive mouse/keyboard input.  I was hoping I could just create and image from the applet graphics and paint the image to my JPanel, but perhaps that is not possible.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @TonyDepace: why did you not tell us this and other details from the get go? What's wrong with using the glass pane for this? Again, for better answers, please provide more of the details of your problem.

Comment: @TonyDepace Are you the author of the Applet?  You could add a flag within the Applet to ignore input when in its frozen state.

Comment: hovercraft, I didn't think it would help @ the time, sorry.  and @Nathaniel, I am not the author of the applet, it is loaded using a url classloader.  I am designing a modified client.